# При вводе текста выдает ошибку NameError [Python & Kivy]

Tags: python, kivy

Код:

```
def on_enter(instance):
    if instance.text.startswith('192.168'):
        global auth
        auth = True
        try:
            client.connect((str(instance.text), 5634))
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print("Неверный IP-Адресс")
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Произошла неизвестная ошибка: " + ex)
        else:
            global sm
            sm.current = 'main'
    else:
        print("Неверное значение IP-Адресса")

Builder.load_string(f"""
<LoginScreen>:
    TextInput:
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: on_enter()
<MainScreen>:
    Button:
        text: '{IsComputerOn}'
""")
```

Но когда текст уже введён в поле, при нажатии на Enter выдаёт данную ошибку:

```
NameError: name 'on_enter' is not defined
```

Когда работал без языка разметки Kivy, всё было хорошо. Уже пытался переставлять всё местами, но ничего не помогает. Почему так?

Comment: Давайте угадаю. `on_enter` внутри какого-то класса находится?

Comment: @CrazyElf Нет, он без класса.

Comment: Ну тогда не знаю. Нужно спеца по kivy какого-нибудь подождать.